# Groovy Gorm catch util.JDBCExceptionReporter error on save()

Tags: exception, grails, groovy, save, grails-orm

I have a problem to catch util.JDBCExceptionReporter during save().
Code:

```
  membership.withTransaction { status ->
  try{
    def membership = membership.findByUserId(userId)
    if(!membership){
      membership = new membership(userId: userId, email: userEmail, baseLevel: membership.findByName(membershipName.MEMBER)).save(flush: true)
    }
  }catch(org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException e){
    status.setRollbackOnly()
    return false
  }catch(all){
    println "Insert Membership Exception.\n User Id: $userId\n " + e
  }
```

When I create two thread to run this code, it throw a error:

```
2014-05-06 12:53:07,034 [Actor Thread 5] ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - Duplicate entry 'test@gmail.com' for key 'email'
```

I don't want to show this error every time when their has two threads doing the same insert, because the first thread will go through and insert successfully, so I don't really care about second one.

My question is how to catch util.JDBCExceptionReporter?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As lsidroGH said, `util.JDBCExceptionReporter` is not an exception, it's a log message. It logs both `SQLExceptions` and `SQLWarnings`. There is no problem with your code, as one thread will have a `save()` call that returns `true` and the other thread's `save()` will get `false`.

If you don't want this message to show up in your logs, you will need to increase your log level for `org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter` from `ERROR` to `FATAL` but this will potentially exclude valid exceptions you would want logged. Your best bet is to ignore it, as your code works.

Answer (score 1):

Just guessing:

By default Grails doesn't throw exceptions when saving. To throw integrity exceptions you have to use `save(failOnError: true)`.

So in this case, it's just an internal trace (`util.JDBCExceptionReporter` is not an exception).

In your case, instead of capturing exceptions I'd use `validate` before saving so you can get the integrity errors before trying to save.

Comment: I think validation doesn't work when there has two thread trying to insert in the same time, I tried to use if(membership.validate()){membership.save(flush: true, validate: true)} but still no luck.